# ComboBox like in Windows 10 Calculator app

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

Screenshot of ComboBox in the Windows 10 Calculator App

[image: [1]]

In UWP, there is a builtin style for Buttons that makes it like a link, the TextBlockButtonStyle.

I'd like to replicate the style of the ComboBox in the Windows 10 Calculator app like I posted above.

I tried to edit the default style of ComboBox but I am not sure if this is the part where the "Selected Text" appears in the style:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
           Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
           Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}" />
</ContentPresenter>
```

And if that is the right part to edit, how will I start? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a question? As it stands, you haven't asked one that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Post a complete set of content so people if they want can download or recreate what you are looking for.  What you're asking is to have someone else do it for you, not what you've tried.  The sample above is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Re-Template your control for this to work.

The Border on the actual `ComboBox` can be removed using `BorderBrush="{x:Null}"`

But the actual `Pressed` and `Focused` Visual States will still add `BorderBrush` and `Background` to the control. So We need to remove those visual States.

Copy the Style From [ComboBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx).

Give it a Key `x:Key="ComboBoxStyle"`

Once done, Remove contents inside

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
<VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
```

And then Use it like below.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectedIndex="0" 
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" />
```

End Output

[image]

This is not exactly like it is in Calculator App, But you should get an idea.

Play around with the styles and you should be able to get the desired output.